# How to send any data in route.php to controller file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Hi I am new in Laravel.

I have created two side (Admin, User).

I need to call same controller and same function at same time.

**Route file (route.php):**

```
// admin side
Route::get('admin.index', [MainController::class, 'index']);

// user side
Route::get('user.index', [MainController::class, 'index']);
```

**Did it any possible way to call it like :**

**Route file (route.php):**

```
// admin side :
Route::get('admin.index', [MainController::class, 'index'])->with(['name'=>'admin']);

// user side :
Route::get('user.index', [MainController::class, 'index'])->with(['name'=>'user']);
```

**Controller file (MainController.php):**

```
public function index()

{

      if(name == 'admin') {
            // admin stuff.
      } else if(name == 'user') {
            // user stuff.
      }
}
```

Thank you. :)

Comment: Why not your are using default auth middleware? `Route::get('admin.index', [MainController::class, 'index'])->middleware('auth');` not only logged-in user can access this route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// admin side :
Route::get('admin/index/{name}', [MainController::class, 'index']);

// user side :
Route::get('user/index/{name}', [MainController::class, 'index']);

public function index($name)

{
    if($name == 'admin') {
        // admin stuff.
    } else if($name == 'user') {  
        // user stuff.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user has roles, then you can simply do this in the controller

```
public function index()
```

{

```
  if(auth()->user()->role == 'admin') {
        // admin stuff.
  } else if(auth()->user()->role == 'user') {
        // user stuff.
  }
```

}

Or if you want to pass it in request object,

public function index(Request $request)

{

```
  if($request->name == 'admin') {
        // admin stuff.
  } else if($request->name == 'user') {
        // user stuff.
  }
```

}